# How to call to a button on a windows form?

Tags: c#

I have two classes that I am using with this window form. The first one is the actual code class for the form and I have it calling to another class to perform any database operations.

The database class though throws an error because it has to update certain buttons and such on the form when there is certain data.

How can I write it so that when the button needs to be updated it can update it? Like inside of the database class.

I thought about trying:

```
Form1.Radbutton("insert code here");
```

but is that right?

Comment: posting the error that you get would be beneficial

Comment: it just says that the button doesn't exist in current context.

Comment: You cannot "call" a button.  It is an object, not a method.  If you need to "update" it then you probably should consider changing its Text property.  Or Enabled.  Or BackgroundImage.  It is very unclear which could apply.  Much the same for "Form1", it is a *type*.  You need an object reference.

Answer (score 2):

Why not in your database class fire events to update the button text?
That why you can handle to events in the form and update the button.

For example create delegate event

```
public delegate void UpdateButtonText (string text);
public event UpdateButtonText UpdateButtonTextHandler;
```

Call the event

```
protected void RaiseEvent
{
    if (this.UpdateButtonText!= null)
    {
       this.UpdateButtonText(text);
    }
}
```

In your form you can handle the event as such

```
DBClass.UpdateButtonText+=HandleIt;
```

and

```
protected void HandleIt(string text)
{
   btnWhatever.Text = text;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is basically how WPF works (using MVVM), and if you aren't tied to windows forms yet, I would recommend looking into it as it removes almost all of this boilerplate code.